# Does Sarabhai Vs Sarabhai Season 2 have only 10 Episodes?

Tags: sarabhai-vs-sarabhai

I am big fan of Sarabhai Vs Sarabhai TV show. I watched the first season completely, but when I started season 2 it had only 10 episodes, and felt that they didn't finish the story.

Did they really release only 10 episodes in season 2?

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

The second season was ended indicating the possibility of new season but that is highly unlikely due to the poor reception of the second season.

Wikipedia says

> The season 2 was one among the most anticipated sitcom sequels, it opened with positive critical as well as viewer reception but later the show was heavily criticized for poor writing and sets but the performances were praised.